# PHP set global variable as handle for class

Tags: php, oop, global

For some reason, when defining:

```
 function __construct() {
    if(!isset($_GLOBALS["className"])) {
      $_GLOBALS["className"] = new className;
    }
    return true;
  }

 $_GLOBALS["className"]->classMethod();
```

PHP for some reason states that $_GLOBALS["className"] is undefined.

Oh, and the same also occurs even if I set the global value to something else, from within that class.  I can test the value of the global through the construct or some other method, but not outside - it seems that the global is lost outside the class for some reason.

Is there a way to retain the global after declaring it from within an external class?
Any help is sincerely appreciated!

Comment: Is this all the code, or is there more you aren't showing us?  The `__construct()` should be inside a class and the other portion outside the class.

Comment: I know, it's the dysfunctional part.

Comment: Also it's called `$GLOBALS` and not `$_GLOBALS`. (Notice the lack of underscore.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `$GLOBALS` and not `$_GLOBALS`:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

`$_GLOBALS` will just be available in your function scope.